# How can I clear Totem's cache?

Tags: totem, stream, avi

I watched an uploaded movie with Totem. Looks like it saved or cached the movie somewhere because it takes space now from the HDD. I never noticed similar before.

Where does Totem save streamed movies?

Comment: OP seems concerned about cache and not history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [hidden folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470837/how-to-show-hidden-folders-in-14-04-ubuntu) `.cache`  or `.local/share/totem` in the home directory. Archive Manager does usually place temporary files in beginning with `.fr` or `fr` (`fr` for `file-roller` probably). File roller also leaves these temporary folders in other places (usually when it is interrupted).

Also, for clearing disk space in general you can use [`baobab`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/baobab) to scan for what files and folders are taking up space, or [`bleachbit`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/bleachbit) to clear the cache, temporary files etc made by other programs.

This seems to be a common issue, so I would suggest filing a bug against the `file-roller` package [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file-roller/+bugs) or 'upstream' [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=file-roller) (there is a existing similar bug [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=732073) - however it may be a issue related to Totem and/or using File Roller with Totem).

Comment: This is not really an answer. It's written more in the style of a comment.

Comment: It's a half answer, BUT it was close enough to find the problem. Everytime when I replayed the movie Totem saved it automaticaly in to a new file. I thought it's not possible but it is. [Totem makes cache also](http://i.imgur.com/Vx7RgXF.jpg/) at the **/home/user/.cache/** folder. So thanks @wilf.