# How to show hidden folders in File Manager (Nautilus) on Ubuntu?

Tags: nautilus, files, hidden-files

How do you show a hidden folder (whose name starts with `.`) in File Manager a.k.a. Nautilus on Ubuntu?  I am somewhat new to Ubuntu and can't seem to find the "view" menu.

Comment: Press CTRL+H and all hidden folders will appear. Pressing it again will hide all hidden folders.

Comment: Ctrl+H will work in Nautilus, Nemo, Thunar etc, but for Dolphin (KDE's file manager), it may be Alt+. or similar.

Comment: See [How to show hidden files and folder in Ubuntu](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2018/02/how-to-show-hidden-files-and-folder-in.html)

Comment: How do I configure this via the terminal?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

### Ubuntu 17.10 and earlier

Maximize the folder.

```
Go to the top menu -->View->Show hidden files:
```

[image]

Or by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

---

For permanently showing hidden files, you can go to the **Edit>Preferences** menu item as shown below:

[image: preferences]

---

With the terminal you should:

```
cd /path-of-directory 

ls -a
```

Comment: ctrl + H => works !

Answer (score 41):

### Ubuntu 18.04 and newer

The accepted answer is correct for older versions of Ubuntu.

For newer versions, the image displayed below works

In the top right corner of file explorer, there is a menu button displayed as 3 stacked line (hamburger menu), clicking on that will open a modal, on that there is an option ***Show hidden files***

[image: Image 1]

Comment: Wow, that option is buried. I would have never found that on my own.

Comment: This is not a permanent fix; for me, it reverts back to hiding files (v20.04).

Comment: Is there a way to make this permanent?! I've delete my .git files the thousandth time over now...

Comment: This shows hidden files, but not hidden folders.

Answer (score 5):

## Ubuntu 20.04/ 21.04/ 21.10

Using the Nautilus option `Show hidden files` will only resolve the issue temporarily, but there are ways to set this as the default option.

### Terminal

There is a nice one-liner to do this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-hidden-files true
```

The settings will take effect immediately (even for currently running instances).

### with GUI

As posted [above](https://askubuntu.com/a/1352598/1545557) you may install `dconf-editor`

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then search for `show-hidden` and activate the option `org.gnome.nautilus.preferences`.

As you can see in the following screenshot the "same" option also exists for other applications such as the Gtk FileChooser, so make sure you activate the setting where you need it. `dconf-editor` will also show you the key to use for each setting in case you want to set it using `gsettings` as outlined in the first section of this post.

[image: dconf editor search result]

Comment: The terminal one did the trick, thanks a lot! But beware, you wrote "gsettings set" twice.

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 20.04, the UI is updated to show hidden files. I could see hidden files even after closing and re-opening the application.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]its really simple

In Ubuntu 18.04, show hidden files is here as shown in the image above...

Isn't it simple

Enjoy!

Comment: Because this is the simplest method that I know and only few clicks can do your work... enjoy :)

Comment: ok i'll remember that next time

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution for permanently showing hidden files by default.

Using `dconf-editor` you can search `files` and toggle the desired setting:

[image: Search for files in dconf-editor]