# After the Skype update, on Ubuntu 12.04, it crashes directly after log in.

Tags: 12.04, login, skype, crash

That's exactly it. I've done everything every other forum and Google search suggested. (With the exception of one guy saying to delete the /.Skype folder.) I just couldn't find the folder. I'm at an absolute loss here. I have no idea what to do. Every other post I find is from about 2 or more years go. I highly doubt they had the new force-update Skype issue as I'm having.

Comment: Press Control+H and you will be able to see the hidden folder, and delete it. Or run the command `rm -r /home/<USER>/.Skype` http://askubuntu.com/questions/470837/how-to-show-hidden-folders-in-14-04-ubuntu

Comment: @Tim that worked like a charm! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This will display all the hidden files:  `ls -a | egrep '^\.'`
and use:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.Skype
```

to delete the `skype` config directory.

Comment: What is the egrep for? Also, please enclose all code in grave chars - `\`` If you're deleting via terminal,you don't need to see it.

Comment: regular expression for searching the hidden file

Comment: Okay, yeah that works nicely!

Comment: Umm well for a start I'm Tim, and I didn't ask, so I can't and second, I wouldn't anyway. It isn't a very good answer, it had bad formatting until I edited and you just demanded that I accept it...

Comment: @ user314225: be very careful while using `rm-rf` command as `root`!!!