# How to reset KDE desktop to default on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, kde4

KDE and Gnome Desktops were looking awesome on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, today everything seemed ugly. Slim long font, arabic letters in Chromium/Firefox are barely readable no matter how big I made them on system font settings.
How can I get back to my previous looks settings, without compromising other settings and tweaks?

Here are my versions:

`kde4-config -v`:

```
Qt: 4.8.6
KDE Development Platform: 4.13.3
kde4-config: 1.0
```

`kded4 --version`:

```
Qt: 4.8.6
KDE Development Platform: 4.13.3
KDE Daemon: 4.13.3
```

Comment: Have you recently run updates, (un)installed packages, or changed any settings that could of caused this?

Comment: I do a lot of installing as I use it for College projects, but I don't recall any specific change. I noticed this when I restarted my pc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reset your USER kde:

```
mv ~/.kde4 ~/.kde4.old
```

Then restart your pc. It will set your KDE settings to default..

All the setting will be set to default.

Comment: Where can I find  `~/.kde4` ?

Comment: ~ is your home folder just type: mv ~/.kde4 ~/.kde4.old You can find ~/.kde4 @ your /home/yourusername/.kde4

Comment: It may be called just .kde (it is on my [fedora] system)

Comment: As the filename begins with a `.`, it also a hidden file, so you may need to read [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/470837/how-to-show-hidden-folders-in-14-04-ubuntu)

Comment: @LostLife Thanks. it's just .kde, though, not .kde4, as bodhi.zazen said.