# How can I get chrome to stop opening up in incognito? even after purging and reinstalling fresh

Tags: unity, launcher, google-chrome

I tried opening new tab(non-incognito) and then locking that to the lancher. Then unlocking the first icon, But then the second icon just opens incognito tab by default.

Even though I have not made any attempt to make it open by default, and I originally opened a non-incognito tab when I locked the second icon to the launcher.

Im guessing this is not an issue with Chrome rather it is one of Ubuntu because it still occurs after running

Below is a screenshot of the primary issue I'm having with Chrome

[image: This is screenshot of the primary issue Im having with Chrome]

If i start chrome through the original icon that I lock to my launcher after purging and reinstalling a freshly downloaded chrome it looks like the image below.

[image: If i start chrome through the original icon that I lock to my launcher after purging and reinstalling a freshly downloaded chrome it looks like the 2nd image does.]

> sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable

I'd like to know how I get chrome to stop opening in incognito by default and stop showing a website title even after I reinstalling it?

Comment: [Enable "Show hidden files"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/470837/how-to-show-hidden-folders-in-14-04-ubuntu), and then delete `.config/google-chrome/` folder. Does it solve your problem ? Note that this will delete all your chrome data and settings, but this seems to be what you want to do.

Comment: @JonasCz I just did this and still same issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the problem persists, even after completely un-installing / re-installing, I am pretty sure you'll have one or more left-over local `.desktop` file(s) in `~/.local/share/applications`, referring to `Chrome`.

Local `.desktop` files are not removed when you re-install an application.
Chrome is "famous" for creating user-specific `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications`, but they regularly cause unexpected behaviour.

#### What to do

Remove *all* local `.desktop` files, referring to `Chrome` in `~/.local/share/applications`. Then log out and back in. If you are having doubts on a specific `.desktop` file, make it executable to make it show its icon.

You do not need local `.desktop` files, unless you want specific behaviour. As mentioned, `Chrome` is quite "active" in creating local `.desktop` files.

Comment: You were right , Chrome had around 10/12 of the total .desktop files. I followed your instructions and deleted all the chrome.desktop files and loged out and back in and the issue was resolved. I appreciate the advice I'll keep it in mind. I hope other find this useful .

Comment: @jose perfect! Glad it works :)