# How to access Ubuntu ~ and . folder

Tags: directory

I have read many Questions and Answers here. In some of them there are directories that I cannot find on my computer, for example:

```
/home/username/.local/
~/.local/share/Steam
```

What is `~`, what is folder start with `.`, and how I can access these folders?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`~` is a special shell replacement. It's replaced with your home directory (*typically* `/home/$USER` but not neccessarily). It's a shortcut we use because it's nice and short and it's impossible to know everybody's `$HOME`.

Files and directories prepended with a dot are hidden. In Windows it's a boolean setting on files, in Unix it's based on the filename. You can still access them though:

- In Ubuntu's default file browser you can:

  - [Toggle the display of hidden files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470837/how-to-show-hidden-folders-in-14-04-ubuntu)
  - Use the address bar to manually go to the path (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to toggle raw address mode).
  - Use a run dialogue (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) to run `nautilus <full path>`
- In a terminal you can `cd` directly to the path.

Answer (score 0):

`~` is for accessing your home directory , if you type  `cd ~`  you will reach your home directory.

For example you want to go to Music directory from any directory just type:

`cd ~/Music`

If a directory name starts with dot `.` it means that is hidden however you can access it from cd .foldername, also there are other uses of dot like:

1)  `cd .`   u remain in the same folder where you are before entering this command

2) `cd ..`   go to previous folder from the current folder 
NOTE : Folder and Directory are used interchangeably

Comment: Actually `cd ..` takes you to the parent directory, for previous directory use: `cd -`