# Permissiond denied, try to restore google chrome bookmarks.bak

Tags: permissions

I get this error :

```
.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks.bak: Permission denied
```

How can I get acces? I want to be able to change the name in bookmarks, as to restore the bookmarks folder I cut and lost in Chrome. It's a months work in bookmarks and I need it for my study. Anyone please?

Comment: To check the permissions, run `ls -l .config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks.bak`.

Comment: Thanks Mike! This is the answer: -rw------- 1 ninti ninti 958059 sep 22 09:53 .config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks.bak
What to do?

Comment: What command did you run to get the original error? Are you running it as the user `ninti`?

Comment: If you are `ninti`, you should have no problem opening the file with e.g. `gedit ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks.bak` . Otherwise, do `sudo chmod a+r ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks.bak`.

Comment: I am a newbie.... but I am not going to give up on Ubuntu. I didn't know I had to give the command gedit. Now I have permission. Can I just change the name of the Bookmarks.bak file into Bookmarks? THANKS a lot! Without help from this forum I wouldn't be able to work with Ubuntu.

Comment: I do not use Chrome so I don't know what files it wants, but if the `bookmarks.bak` file was just created as copy of a former `bookmarks` file, you should be fine. Maybe you want to rename the current `bookmarks` file to `bookmark.bak2` first, in case it goes wrong?

Comment: `gedit` is just one of the programs you can use to open and/or edit the file. There are others. First, back up your current Bookmarks file (even though it seems useless now): `cd ~/.config/google-chrome/Default` followed by `cp Bookmarks Bookmarks-old`. Then, rename the backup file: `mv Bookmarks.bak Bookmarks`.

Comment: I copied the commands, nothing seems to work, I might not have done it right. This is what shows in the terminal:                                                       cd ~/.config/google-chrome/Default
cp Bookmarks Bookmarks-old
mv Bookmarks.bak Bookmarks

Comment: Try closing Google Chrome when renaming Bookmarks.back, the permissions look ok, nothing to be done there.

Comment: ok, I forgot to close Google Chrome. The permissions are fine. But how to rename it? I've given the commands  as outlined by Jos, nothing happened. Than I put gedit in front of the commands and it opened windows. Can you please tell me step by step how to rename? By save as? I am sorry I know so little...ninti@ninti-K52Jc:~$ gedit mv Bookmarks.bak Bookmarks

(gedit:5838): Gtk-WARNING **: Inhibit called with an unrealized window

Comment: You've got the commands a little mixed up there, `gedit` will take the arguments you've given it as files to open. So you've told `gedit` to open the `mv`, `Bookmarks.bak` and `Bookmarks` files. The `mv` command should should just be `mv Bookmarks.bak Bookmarks`, see my answer.

Comment: I am sorry... I've closed all the windows the terminal opened, without saving changes. And now I get the line: cannot stat ‘/home/ninti/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks.bak’: No such file or directory. So I must have done everything wrong. I need to learn myself a lot! I still have google chrome open, so the bookmarks.bak won't be lost.

Comment: nautilus --browser ~/.config/google-chrome/Default
Thats what you mean with open a file browser I guess? ;)

Comment: I can't find hidden files though..........

Comment: To show hidden files press Ctrl+H and have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/470837/how-to-show-hidden-folders-in-14-04-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

To restore the Chrome bookmarks you need to rename the `Bookmarks.bak` file to `Bookmarks`. To do that you just need to open a file browser and navigate to the `.config/google-chrome/Default` directory. You'll need to show hidden files by going to `View->Show hidden files` first as any directory/folder which starts with a `.` in Linux is hidden. Then with Chrome closed, delete the current `Bookmarks` file and rename the `Bookmarks.bak` file.

Alternatively you can open a terminal and use the `mv` command

```
mv ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks.bak ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Booksmarks
```