# I can't find .themes folder

Tags: themes

I want to install MacOS theme in my Ubuntu, but when I create the `.themes` folder in HOME, the `.themes` folder disapears. Can you help me ? I want my theme :D

Thank YOU very match <3

Answer (score 0):

Files and folders starting with a dot are hidden files in Linux. To show them in the file manager (nautilus?) the standard Keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. To hide them again use the same shortcut.
A relevant link (I hope):
[How to show hidden files in Nautilus 3.20.3 Ubuntu 16.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837878/how-to-show-hidden-files-in-nautilus-3-20-3-ubuntu-16-10)

Or search the internet for "linux show hidden files" and the name of your file manager of choice