# I have a Minecraft world file on a thumb drive and am trying to move it onto my Ubuntu computer

Tags: minecraft

I’m very new to Ubuntu and not sure where to to put my Minecraft world file on to my computer for it to show up on Minecraft

Comment: I just noticed in your question you said world "file". Not trying to nitpick here, but is it a single file? Or a folder with several files in it? If it's one file, it could be compressed or incomplete.

Comment: Is this a Minecraft Client world? Or a Minecraft Server world?

Answer (score 1):

You need to transfer the world files off of the flash drive to `~/.minecraft/saves`. `~`, especially in Linux, is used to represent your home folder, where your Desktop, Documents, etc. are stored. This folder is usually `/home/<username>`. Since `.minecraft` begins with `.`, it is a hidden folder, and will not appear in a file manager. To get around this, you have to either use a terminal (see [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-move-files-in-linux-with-mv-command/)), or instruct your file manager to show hidden files (see here [How to show hidden files in Nautilus 3.20.3 Ubuntu 16.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837878/how-to-show-hidden-files-in-nautilus-3-20-3-ubuntu-16-10). It looks a little different in newer versions, but you did not specify what version of Ubuntu you were using.).

### EDIT

For more information about `.minecraft`, see the wiki page [here](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/.minecraft).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a Minecraft Server world, then it depends upon where your Minecraft Server is installed.

Let's say that I have a Minecraft server, and I'm not quite sure where it is installed.

- I can find it by looking for any file that is known to be part of the server. Example: `eula.txt`.
- Let's limit the search to /home directories because that's where most folks download the server.jar file to.

```
$ find /home -name eula.txt
/home/minecraft/eula.txt
```

My minecraft server is located at /home/minecraft. Yours might be in a different place.

My minecraft world is therefore located in /home/minecraft/world. Let's check that and verify that all my world-related files and subdirectories are there.

```
$ ls /home/minecraft/world
DIM-1  advancements  datapacks  level.dat_old  poi     session.lock
DIM1   data          level.dat  playerdata     region  stats
```