# Where does `mv myfolder ..myfolder` move my file to?

Tags: mv

I am inside `/home/me/examplefolder` and tried to move the folder `myfolder` to `/home/me` like this:

```
root@linuxserver:/home/me/examplefolder# mv myfolder/ ..myfolder
```

The folder `myfolder` dissapeared, but I cant find it now, where is it?

Comment: In order to move it up into the parent directory, you'll want to use `mv myfolder/ ../myfolder`, because ../myfolder refers to a location while ..myfolder is just a new name for it

Comment: [Wrong mv command - where did my files go?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342828/wrong-mv-command-where-did-my-files-go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is at "..myfolder"

You have to show hidden or "dot" directories

`ls -la` or show hidden directories in Nautilus

[How to show hidden folders in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470837/how-to-show-hidden-folders-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: So it is in `/home/me/examplefolder` ?

Comment: Yes, you forgot the / `mv foo ../` If you are not changing the name you do not need to retype the name to move up.