# Nautilus and Nemo do not find hidden files in search

Tags: nautilus, search

Both Nautilus and Nemo don't find hidden files (those starting with `.`) in the search.

For example, if I search (`CTRL+F`) `.fileName` it says `0 files found` even if the file exists!

How to solve this?
There is an option to check or is a giant bug?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's intended.  Files with "." as their first character are not intended for user files, but configs for programs and thus are wanted to be *hidden* in most cases (unless the operator/user uses the option to include them). There are options to include hidden files, but I don't know your OS/release.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show hidden folders in File Manager (Nautilus) on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470837/how-to-show-hidden-folders-in-file-manager-nautilus-on-ubuntu)

Comment: thanks, can you suggest me how to include them? I'm using 20.04 LTS

Comment: Nope. I already set to show hidden files

Comment: It works well for me in both Nemo and Nautilus.

Comment: @pLumo did you set something?

Comment: No, just use ctrl+h to toggle showing hidden files.

Comment: @pLumo I see hidden files in the listed files but Nautilus does not find them when I search with `CTRL+F`

Comment: Not normal behaviour. I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: I also have this on both Nemo and Nautilus. My workaround is to use `find -iname '.name'` from the terminal.