# Ubuntu low memory after playing videos from .zip file

Tags: hard-drive, video, totem, zip, tmp

I have a .zip file that is 4Gb of size and has videos, after trying to play some of them directly from the .zip file just by double clicking I noticed that I was running low on HD memory so I restarted my machine to see if the temporary files would be deleted. The memory was not restored and the /tmp folder did not have any files bigger than Kbs. Please note that the .zip file is on my windows (/host) folders and the player I used was tottem and the "Archive Manager" to decompress. I was down to 28Mb free of HD space.

Comment: Are the files in `~/.cache`?

Comment: @Wilf thank you, impressively the files were there in folders named as '.fr-' .   even found old files and was able to free a good amount of space thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I clear Totem's cache?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/341413/how-can-i-clear-totems-cache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the folder `~/.cache`.

Archive Manager/Totem probably will cache the video files there as Totem and most other media players need to be able to read from the file directly.

Archive Manager does usually place temporary files in beginning with `.fr` or `fr` (`fr` for `file-roller` probably). File roller also leaves these temporary folders in other places (usually when it is interrupted). Also, for clearing disk space in general you can use [`baobab`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/baobab) to scan for what files and folders are taking up space.

This seems to be a common issue *(I have had it occasionally, and answered [a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341413/how-can-i-clear-totems-cache) a while ago)*, so I would suggest filing a bug against the `file-roller` package *([here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file-roller/+bugs) or 'upstream' [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=file-roller) -however it may be a issue related to Totem and/or using File Roller with Totem)*.